# В каком числе должно быть слово "доза" в "в дозе 50 мг или 100 мг на неделях 0 и 2, а затем – в той же дозе каждый месяц"?

Tags: единственное-множественное-число, или

> Пациенты получали препарат в **дозе** 50 мг или 100 мг на неделях 0 и 2, а затем – в той же **дозе** каждый месяц.

Подскажите, в каком числе должно быть слово "доза" в выделенных местах? Речь о клиническом исследовании. Под "или" имеется в виду, что пациентов разбивали на две группы, пациентам в одной группе вводили 50 мг, пациентам в другой группе – 100 мг. Счет неделей ведется от начала исследования.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предложение записано верно: ***Пациенты получали препарат в дозе 50 мг или 100 мг на неделях 0 и 2, а затем – в той же дозе каждый месяц.***

*Препарат в дозе 50 мг или 100 мг* – в этом сочетании формы  *в дозе 50 мг, в дозе 100 мг* можно рассматривать как **несогласованные определения** к существительному "препарат". Тогда можно применить правило Розенталя о двух определениях при одном существительном при наличии **разделительного союза ИЛИ.**

Сравнить:  Пациенты получали препарат в дозе 50 мг или **(в дозе)** 100 мг.

Правило:

[http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#з_04](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#%D0%B7_04)

§194. Два определения при одном существительном

1. Имя существительное, которому предшествует два или несколько определений, указывающих на разновидности предметов, ставится **в форме единственного числа:**

   если между определениями стоят противительные, **разделительные** или сопоставительные союзы, например: не норвежский, а голландский конькобежец; латинский или готический шрифт; то широкая, то узкая дорога; как в прошлом, так и в нынешнем году; если не в соседнем, то в более отдаленном регионе;